# AutoCAD drawing (DWG) to map tiles

Tags: vector, autocad, dwg, maptiler

Rendering large DWG files as such has shown performance degradation to large extent. Planning to use the concept of map tiles using leaflet. Need some pointers/information on how to convert DWG files to map tiles.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After too many hours, searching everywhere for a solution to convert DWG/DXF files using any automated command line tool, finally I found [QCAD.org](http://www.qcad.org/en/).

And that works even on Windows, MacOS and Linux.

After a quick look in documentation, I found [the section for command line tools](http://www.ribbonsoft.com/en/qcad-documentation/qcad-command-line-tools).

They are:

```
dwg2bmp, dwg2png, dwg2jpeg, dwg2tiff, dxf2png, dxf2jpeg, dxf2tiff
```

and the awesome:

```
dwg2maptiles and dxf2maptiles
```

Using this tool, they came up with a beautiful sample using leaflet.js:
http://qcad.org/res/map/

> The project is OpenSource, but this scripts are only avaliable at **QCAD Professional** edition.
>   You can use the free open source QCAD Community Edition by downloading the trial version for your platform (Win, Mac, Linux) and then remove the QCAD Professional add-on running in trial mode. Alternatively, you may compile your own package from sources.

*PS: I'm very happy to support the project buying a professional copy.*

Answer (score 2):

The easiest approach may be to save your DWG files as PDF and use [MapTiler](http://www.maptiler.com) to create the raster tiles and leaflet viewer for you.

You can render such PDF by drag&drop into MapTiler while choosing the "raster" profile - just follow the video tutorial: https://youtu.be/9iYKmRsGoxg?list=PLGHe6Moaz52PiQd1mO-S9QrCjqSn1v-ay

If you need to assign coordinates for later on placing markers or polygons on specified position over the DWG tiles - it is possible with advanced tiles.

If you need help with using MapTiler - write details and provide sample file you need to process to https://www.maptiler.com/support/community/.

If you data are sensitive or you need a guarantee on the answering of your request you seek directly the support from us, the authors of MapTiler.